# Glut in Dev C++ error "redeclaration of C++ built-in type `short'"

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-construction, glut, dev-c++

I have this simple triangle drawing code and it produces an error "redeclaration of C++ built-in type short ". But When I put `#include<iostream.h>` before `#include<glut.h>`, it compiles and runs.
Can anyone explain the logic behind that?

```
#include<glut.h>
void renderScene(void) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0.0);
    glEnd();

        glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // init GLUT and create Window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
    glutCreateWindow("My first program");

    // register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);

    // enter GLUT event processing cycle
    glutMainLoop();
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Is the primary question "why does it work when I put iostream.h first"?

Comment: @wallyk This would be better title! But I need the reason why it works?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the preprocessor output of both versions, maybe you can spot the reason there.

Comment: Please post the complete compiler invocation and output.

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem, but iostream is not a .h file, you should use '#include <iostream>' without '.h' at the end.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy

**1 C:\Dev-Cpp\triangle.cpp In file included from triangle.cpp
45 C:\Dev-Cpp\include\glut.h redeclaration of C++ built-in type short
 C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [triangle.o] Error 1**

Comment: Compile log
**Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c triangle.cpp -o triangle.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"   

In file included from triangle.cpp:1:
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/glut.h:45: error: redeclaration of C++ built-in type `short'

make.exe: *** [triangle.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
**

Comment: @Kevin It is working code but I was just wondering **why does it work when I put iostream.h first**

Comment: Consider using a modern C++ compiler, e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your exact glut.h and library versions, but I see roundabout line 45 of glut.h:

```
   /* XXX This is from Win32's <ctype.h> */
#  ifndef _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
typedef unsigned short wchar_t;
#   define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#  endif
```

If `wchar_t` is already defined (to `short` for example), but the `_WCHAR_T_DEFINED` macro is not, the line will then be treated as:

```
typedef unsigned short short;
```

Which is a redeclaration of the built-in type. `<iostream>` (don't use the .h btw, it's not used anymore per standard) is adding defines such that the typedef is not executed, or undef'ing `wchar_t` if it is a macro such that the typedef is legal.

Comment: And this is why `typedef` is better than `#define` for stuff like this.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Thanks for reply. I downloaded all files from [here] (http://chortle.ccsu.edu/Bloodshed/glutming.zip)

Answer (score 3):

I faced `error redeclaration of c++ built-in type 'wchar_t'` at the time of my car racing project. I searched in Google, but didn't find any solution to solve my problem :-(

But later, I solved this problem by including "windows.h" by myself :-)

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
```

`#include<windows.h>` has to be added at the top. If it's added under `glut.h` there will be an error.

`#include<bits/stdc++.h>` just added for safety :-p

Use `#include<GL/glut.h>` or `#include<glut.h>` depending on the folder where `glut.h` has been placed.

Comment: *#include<bits/stdc++.h> just added for safety* Aargh! Don't ever recommend using that header: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and change the wchar_t variable name to wchar_tt in the "glut.h" file and it works fine.

```
#  ifndef _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
typedef unsigned short wchar_tt;
#   define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#  endif
# endif
```