# Glut wchar_t redeclaration

Tags: c++, glut

This question isn't a duplicate. I have searched the web for around 4 hours and found nothing. I am using codeblocks ide and when I try to compile my glut app, it says include file:

> (1)\include\GL\glut.h|50|error: redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'wchar_t' [-fpermissive]|.

My libraries and things are linked properly.

Why is it doing this? Is there a simple way I can fix the problem?

Comment: Try changing the order of glut headers. Keep them at the top of standard headers.

Comment: @Mahesh Yeah but I only have one header which is glut.h

Comment: Check [this SO thread.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958218/glut-in-dev-c-error-redeclaration-of-c-built-in-type-short)