# redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'wchar_t' windows 10 glut cpp

Tags: c++, glut

I'm trying to run some Glut app in c++, but my codeblocks gives me an error

```
redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'wchar_t'
```

and it points into glut.h file line 50 :

```
typedef unsigned short wchar_t;
```

I've downloaded this program and moved all src files in new codeblocks project

http://www.mindcontrol.org/~hplus/graphics/fire-particles.html

how to fix it?

Comment: `wchar_t` is a built in type:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types  best bet is to comment out the line and see what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glut in Dev C++ error "redeclaration of C++ built-in type \`short'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958218/glut-in-dev-c-error-redeclaration-of-c-built-in-type-short)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the sane problem. And that is how I have solved the problem.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

<**windows.h**> should be added at first or it will show a error. I hope it will solve the problem
Thanks

Comment: It was asked like 1y ago mate ;) I solved it by compiling on Windows XP.