# redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'wchar_t' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, glut

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "sainaintque.h"

using namespace std;


#include <windows.h>
#include <glut.h>

void lineSegment(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glVertex2i (180, 15);
  glVertex2i (10, 145);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
}

void glDemo()
{
    int argc = 1;
    glutInit(&argc, nullptr);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
    glutCreateWindow("Example OpenGL Program");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 160.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(lineSegment);
    glutMainLoop();
}

int main()
{


    sainaIntQue *sa = new sainaIntQue();

    sa->process("C:\\Users\\19593\\Documents\\qt\\build-print3d-Desktop_Qt_5_14_2_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\\all\\",
                "C:\\Users\\19593\\Documents\\qt\\build-print3d-Desktop_Qt_5_14_2_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\\all_Sec\\",
                2200, 2090, 1428, 15, true);



    cout<<"finished!!!"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I ran the above code using qt and got the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j8cb.png)

I look for the error at the following location of glut.h

```
#  ifndef _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
typedef unsigned short wchar_t;
#   define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#  endif
```

How do I fix it？

I found a similar problem, but the solution didn't solve my problem
[redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'wchar_t' windows 10 glut cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853339/redeclaration-of-c-built-in-type-wchar-t-windows-10-glut-cpp)

Comment: Try adding `#define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED` before including `glut.h`.  Also, please include all error messages as text, rather than images.  Images are not searchable and not everyone is lucky enough to be able to see them.  Thx.

Comment: I'd remove the typedef entirely.    `wchar_t` is a *language keyword* in C++, so redefining it is an error (even if some C++ compilers can be forced to accept it).    If you need to compile code using `wchar_t` with a C compiler (since `wchar_t` is not a language keyword in C), then only have the typedef when compiling as C (and, obviously, avoid using any C++ specific code when compiling as C).    If the offending code is in a third-party header, contact the developer of that header, and suggest they fix it.

Comment: @peter _If the offending code is in a third-party header:_ it is.